# how to pass data/value name in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const {
    name,
    email,
    location
  } = organization || {};
```

How can I pass value of 'name' from this constant variable in a component to another component?

Answer (score 0):

```
const {
    name,
    email,
    location,
    needs,
    about = "",
    objectives = {},
    urls = {},
  } = organization || {};

<OtherComponent name={name} />
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as a prop to the component you want. Here's an example:

```
// Parent.js

import Child from "./Child.js";

const {
    name,
    email,
    location,
    needs,
    about = "",
    objectives = {},
    urls = {},
} = organization || {};

const Parent = () => <Child name={name || ""} />

// Child.js

return Child = ({name}) => <h1>Hello {name}</h1>
```

This is a pattern you'll see all over React. If you want to data between sibling components instead of between parent and child, then you should use the `context` API

Comment: I believe in child component, we need to use 'props.name' instead of 'name'.

Comment: @BharanidharReddy The `name` prop is being destructured off of props in the params of the `Child` function

Answer (score 0):

We can pass the data to another component using props.

then we can access this props in childComponent like
this.props.name